# How to get value from radio buttons on form submit

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I have two radio buttons:

```
<input dojoAttachPoint="sensorSwipe" id="sensorSwipe" type="radio" 
                            dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" name="Sensor" checked /> 
                        <input dojoAttachPoint="sensorContinuous" id="sensorContinuous"  type="radio" 
                            dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" name="Sensor" />
```

...that I'm submitting in a form using an dojo xhrpost call:

```
dojo.xhrPost({
        url: baseUrl + path,
        form: form,
        timeout: 60000,
        load: function(result) { PostSuccess(result, path, callbackFunction); },
        error: function(error, args) { AjaxError(error, args, path, request, callbackFunction); }
    });
```

The issue is that when submitting the form, it sends a "Sensor" property with a value of "on", regardless of which of the two radio buttons is selected. How can I tell which radio button was selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `value` attribute to the `<input>` to specify the value.